# How to disable position change of JSlider on mouse right click

Tags: java, swing, awt, jslider

I am using a `JSlider` in my application. I want only left click to slide `JSlider`, and I want to disable right click for `JSlider`. I am able to get event on right click, but slider is changing its value to other position.

```
jSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        //code
    }
});

jSlider.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        if (e.getButton() == java.awt.event.MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
            //code
        } else {
            //code
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using JDK1.7.0_03, Windows 7

```
UIManager.put("Slider.onlyLeftMouseButtonDrag", Boolean.TRUE);
```

JDK1.6.0_31:

[Bug ID: 6614972 JSlider value should not change on right-click](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6614972)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalSliderUI;

public class SliderOnlyLeftMouseButtonDragTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JSlider slider00 = new JSlider(0,10,5);
    JSlider slider01 = new JSlider(0,10,5);
    slider01.setUI(new MetalSliderUI() {
      protected TrackListener createTrackListener(JSlider slider) {
        return new TrackListener() {
          @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if(!SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
              return;
            }
            super.mousePressed(e);
          }
        };
      }
    });
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(slider00);
    p.add(slider01);
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new SliderOnlyLeftMouseButtonDragTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thaks , but this is an existing application and i am using JAVA 6. Do we have solution in java 6..?

Comment: good track down of the bug :-) On-the-fly subclassing of ui-delegates and setting them per-instance has disadvantages, though, in f.i. not surviving a call to updateUI.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to work around bugs in ui listeners is to

- find the listener
- implement a wrapper which delegates to the original only if appropriate (here: not for right button)
- remove the original and add the wrapper

The slight advantage compared with @aterai's approach is that it's independent of LAF, that is you can apply it in the exact same manner for each instead of subclassing the ui delegate for each.

In code something like:

```
MouseListener[] listeners = slider.getMouseListeners();
MouseListener uiListener = null;
for (MouseListener l : listeners) {
    LOG.info(l.getClass().getName());
    if (l.getClass().getName().contains("Track")) {
        uiListener = l; 
        break;
    }
}

final MouseListener delegate = uiListener;
MouseListener wrapper = new MouseListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (filter(e)) return;
        delegate.mouseClicked(e);
    }

    private boolean filter(MouseEvent e) {
        return SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (filter(e)) return;
        delegate.mousePressed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (filter(e)) return;
        delegate.mouseReleased(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        delegate.mouseEntered(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        delegate.mouseExited(e);
    }

};
slider.removeMouseListener(uiListener);
slider.addMouseListener(wrapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Case he is not working with 1.7
First you must remove all mouseListeners from your slider

```
for (MouseListener ml : slider.getMouseListeners()){
    slider.removeMouseListener(ml);
}
```

after that you can implement your own mouseListener and add that one to the slider. In your mouselistener you must implement the calculations to set the value of your slider... e.g. sth like

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    if (e.getButton() == java.awt.event.MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
        //code whatever should happen on right click
    } else {
        e.getX()*slider.getMaximum()/slider.getWidth();
    }

}
```

I guess the calculation could be improved because of rounding and so on.. But this idea should lead you to success

Comment: Yes i understand, but problem is JSlider calling stateChanged event before mouseReleased event and changing its position.so i want to disable right click on JSlider before  mouseReleased.

Comment: Are you sure you have removed all MouseListeners before you added yours?